# 'No type was found that matches the controller named' error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webapi

I have an Asp.Net Web Forms app that I am trying to add a webapi controller to. When I call the URI for the controller, I get the 'No type was found that matches the controller named' error. I have read through all the threads here and on other sites but no resolution as yet.

My controller class has the following:

```
`public class RelationalController : ApiController{

    [System.Web.Http.ActionName("InitializeClient")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public Dictionary<string, object> 
InitializeClient(Dictionary<string, object> jsonResult)
    {
        this.BindData();
        return pivotClient.GetJsonData(jsonResult["action"].ToString(), 
ProductSales.GetSalesData(), jsonResult["clientParams"].ToString());
    }
}`
```

I have the following setup in Global.asax.cs:

`

```
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes();
        }

        protected static void RegisterRoutes()
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Relational",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Relational", id = 
    System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }`
```

When I test the call in Postman I get the following:

{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:57802/api/Relational/InitializeClient/'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'Relational'."}

I've verified I only have one controller named RelationalController. It's the only controller defined in the app. It's in a folder call api at the root of my app.

Does anyone know what might be the issue, or can you suggest some ways to troubleshoot further?

Answer (score 1):

you can try attribute routing. Add  MapMvcAttributeRoutes()

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute(“{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}”);
 
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
 
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: “Default”,
        url: “api/{controller}/{action}/{id}”,
        defaults: new { controller = “Home”, action = “Index”, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

and change the action

```
[HttpPost("~/api/Relational/InitializeClient")]
public Dictionary<string, object> InitializeClient(Dictionary<string, object> jsonResult)
```